Generating an Image URL using html-to-image, canvas, and jsdom not working
I'm trying to generate an image of simple HTML document using SVG's but even this simple example errors out with "Unsupported image type."
I do not want to use puppeteer or any headless browser.
const dom = new JSDOM(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <div id="capture" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: lightblue;">
          <p style="color: black; font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">Capture this element</p>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);

Generating the image URL with this code:
toPng(captureElement).then( dataUrl => {
    console.log(dataUrl);
}).catch( err => {
    console.error("Error rendering image:", err);
});

Give the error Error rendering image: Error: Unsupported image type
I'm trying to do this in a Node.js environment along with a Discord bot, if that has any importance.
Any alternative ways to accomplish what I'm trying would be appreciated as much as a solution.
I tried setting up as close to a browser environment as possible like this:
global.document = dom.window.document;
global.window = dom.window;
global.navigator = dom.window.navigator;
global.HTMLCanvasElement = createCanvas;
global.HTMLVideoElement = class HTMLVideoElement {};
global.HTMLIFrameElement = class HTMLIFrameElement {};
global.HTMLTextAreaElement = class HTMLTextAreaElement {};
global.HTMLInputElement = class HTMLInputElement {};
global.Element = class Element {};
global.HTMLSelectElement = class HTMLSelectElement {};
global.SVGImageElement = class SVGImageElement {};
global.HTMLImageElement = class {
    constructor() {
      this.src = ""; // Placeholder for src attribute
    }
  };
  global.Image = Image;
global.XMLSerializer = class {
    serializeToString(node) {
      return dom.serialize();
    }
  };
global.window.getComputedStyle = function () {
    return {
        getPropertyValue: (prop) => {
        if (prop === "display") return "block"; // Default display
        return ""; // Default for other properties
        },
    };
};

I've tried using dom-to-image, the predecessor of html-to-image, but it throws Error rendering image: Error: error while reading from input stream in the same scenario.

I'm afraid you can't do this in a node.js environment. "html-to-image" heavily depends on browser APIs for canvas and CSS to render HTML to a SVG foreignObject and eventually this svg to canvas to retrieve a raster image. You would need a full-fledged CSS and canvas emulation for node. There are canvas modules but afaik they only support native canvas drawing API commands
